# Does the operand of logical negation have a name?

Tags: logic

Conjunction has "conjunct".
Disjunction has "disjunct".
Implication has "antecedent" and "consequent".

Does the operand of negation have a name?

Comment: Negated sentence/formula?

Comment: My best suggestion is "negation input". I have a related question: do the left and right sides of a biconditional have their own names too? Please ping me if answering this.

Comment: @ryang I recommend (but have never seen, sadly) "dextrant" and "sinistrant."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Okay, the root meaning of "dex" is right/good, and the root meaning of "sini" is my, whereas "trant" means entrant/input, right? This is even more obscure than 'negand'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The operand of negation is the negand. I do not think it is a very commmon word, but [this site](https://www.wordsense.eu/negand/) cites a few sources in which it is used.

Comment: The -end/-and suffixes, meaning "that which does or receives an action", fills a lot of obscure corners. "Repetend" is the name for the repeating part of a repeating decimal. A sum has two "addends", while a subtraction has a "minuend" and a "subtrahend".

Comment: Ah, nice. Google didn't suggest this word when I searched for "negant" and "negatant" before. 2:20 of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zh078M2TcK8) uses this word.